# Can I use Compression in WCF?

Tags: wcf, performance, http-compression

we hosted WCF services in IIS 5.1 wndows xp sp3 with **httpBasicBinding**. 
The data tranferered is huge in size and  transfered every 1 minute. 
For this to less data transfer **Is it possible to compress the response of WCF service** by using **default http compression** ? Can I have some sample code / article ***for using http comression in WCF***?
  
 nRk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a project on [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/wcfextensions) available, I've used it successfully in projects.

Comment: Thank Benny for quick reply.
There it is indicating custom binding, If I custom binding, can this WCF service will be able accessed by .net 2.0 clients?

Comment: In the 2.0 world (on both client and server) I've added compression to webservices by using a SoapExtension. 

If you use this WCF extension you'll have to find a way on your 2.0 .NET client to decompress/compress your requests / responses. If it's soap, a SoapExtension would be the right place to do that.

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/5c67b0da-9e50-4ee1-b7ac-a4733c580980/

Anyway, have you considered compressing the data before it is sent, and uncompressing it back upon reception?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to explore the streaming capabilities of WCF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx